# Subset OR Not a Subset

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Fill in the black using $\subseteq$ OR $\not \subset $

***Are my answers correct?***

{$\frac {x} {x+1} : x\in \mathbb {N}$} __ $\mathbb {Q}$

ANSWER: $\not \subset $

$\mathbb {Z} \cup [-1,1]$ __ $[-2,2]

ANSWER: $\subseteq$

$\mathbb {N} $ x $\mathbb {Z}$   **__**  $\mathbb {Z} $ x $\mathbb {N}$

ANSWER: $\not \subset $

$\mathbb {Z} $ x $\mathbb {N}$   **__**   $\mathbb {N} $ x $\mathbb {Z}$

ANSWER: $\not \subset $

Comment: wrong, wrong, right, right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last two are correct: $\langle 1,-1\rangle$ is in $\Bbb N\times\Bbb Z$ but not in $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb N$, and $\langle -1,1\rangle$ is in $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb N$ but not in $\Bbb N\times\Bbb Z$. The first two, however, are wrong.

- If $x\in\Bbb N$, then $x+1\in\Bbb N$ and $x+1\ne 0$, so $\frac{x}{x+1}\in\Bbb Q$. Thus, $\left\{\frac{x}{x+1}:x\in\Bbb N\right\}\subseteq\Bbb Q$.
- $3\in\Bbb Z\cup[-1,1]$, but $3\notin[-2,2]$, so $\Bbb Z\cup[-1,1]\nsubseteq[-2,2]$.

Comment: @user113609: You’re welcome.

Comment: WOW just saw your profile and you are person with best score in mse. i wish one day i could be as smart as you. btw congrats on being the number 1, must it feel like heaven being the best in mse??

Comment: @user113609: Thanks! I have an unfair advantage, though: being retired, I’ve more time to spend here than most other users.