# Prove that $\sqrt[n]{n} > \sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$ without calculus?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality, radicals

I'm stuck with this sample RMO question I came across:

> Determine the largest number in the infinite sequence $\sqrt[1]{1}$, $\sqrt[2]{2}$, $\sqrt[3]{3}$, ..., $\sqrt[n]{n}$, ...

In the solution to this problem, I found the solver making the assumption, 
$\sqrt[n]{n}>\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$ for $n \geq 3$ How would you prove this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: In this competition, you aren't allowed to use calculus. Non-calculus methods would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not true when $n=1$ or $n=2$.

Comment: Made the edit. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: A few posts about this (or an equivalent problem):
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331015/which-of-the-numbers-1-21-2-31-3-41-4-51-5-61-6-71-7
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887170/how-to-prove-this-n1n-nn1-for-space-n-ge-3
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77935
You can also try searching in approach0 for the [this nequality](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24n%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%3C(n%2B1)%5En%24&p=1) or [this inequality](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csqrt%5Bn%5Dn%3C%5Csqrt%5Bn%2B1%5D%7Bn%2B1%7D%24&p=1) or for another equivalent form.

Comment: BTW in some of the threads linked above you can find proofs avoiding calculus. In case you have some link to the collection of "sample RMO questions" where this is from, maybe you could add the link - I would consider it as one of several possible ways of [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) to your question.

Comment: Hey Martin. Unfortunately, this question was taken from a book, and not a website. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $n\geq 3.$ Start with this calculation:

$$\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n} = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = 1+\binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{n} +\binom{n}{2}\frac{1}{n^2} + \binom{n}{3}\frac{1}{n^3} +\cdots + \frac{1}{n^n}.$$

In the $k$th term, the numerator of the binomial coefficient is $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)$ which is less than $n\cdot n\cdots n=n^k.$  So the binomial expansion above is less than

$$1+1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots \frac{1}{n!},$$

which, in turn is less than

$$1+1+ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2} + \cdots +\frac{1}{2^n} < 3\leq n. $$

So we have $$n > \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}$$

$$n^{n+1} > (n+1)^n$$

$$n^{(n+1)/n} > n+1$$

$$n^{1/n} > (n+1)^{1/(n+1)}.$$

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

consider the function $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ for $x >0$. Now check it's monotonicity.
\begin{align*}
\ln f(x) & = \frac{\ln x}{x}\\
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} & = \frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}\\
f'(x) & = f(x)\left[\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}\right]
\end{align*}
Observe that for $x >e$, we get $f'<0$. So for $n \geq 3$, we have $f(n) > f(n+1)$.

Comment: Non-calculus method?

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that $$n^{\frac{1}{n}}>(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$$ or
$$\frac{\ln{n}}{n}>\frac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1}.$$
Let $f(x)=\frac{\ln{x}}{x}$, where $x>0$.

Thus, $$f'(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{x}\cdot x-\ln{x}}{x^2}=\frac{1-\ln{x}}{x^2}<0$$
for all $x>e$.

Thus, for all $n\geq3$ we have
$$n^{\frac{1}{n}}>(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}.$$ 
Now, for $n=2$ we get
$$\sqrt2<\sqrt[3]3,$$
and for $n=1$ we have $1^1<2^\frac{1}{2}$, which gives that $\sqrt[3]3$ is a largest number in the  sequence.

Done!

Comment: How would you prove this?

Comment: @user2606764 I added something. See now.

Comment: Early comment... Thanks a lot! How would you solve this without using calculus though?

Comment: @user2606764 You are welcome!

Comment: Just made an edit.

Comment: Non-calculus method?

Comment: @user2606764: Without using calculus, try to prove that $$\sqrt[3+n]{3+n}\lt\sqrt[3]3$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-The function $f(x)=x^{\frac 1x}$ has as derivative $f'(x)=-x^{\frac 1x-2}(\ln(x)-1)$ which prove that $f$ is decreasing on $x\gt e$
You can deduce that the maximum value is $\color{red}{\sqrt[3]3\approx1.442249}$ (verifying that $\sqrt2\approx1.414243$).

Comment: Non-calculus method?

Comment: Prove that $$(3+n)^{\frac{1}{3+n}}\lt3^{\frac13}$$ You have 
$$3+n\lt3\cdot3^{\frac n3}$$  $$n=1\Rightarrow4\lt4.32....\\n=2\Rightarrow5\lt6.24....\\n=3\Rightarrow6\lt9$$ For $n\gt3$ it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

We wish to compare $\sqrt[n]n \lessgtr \sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$. Raise each side to the $n(n+1)$th power to get
$$ n^{n+1} \lessgtr (n+1)^n $$
and use the binomial theorem on the right-hand side:
$$ n\cdot n^n \lessgtr \underbrace{n^n+\binom n1 n^{n-1} + \binom n2 n^{n-2} + \cdots + \binom n{n-1} n^1}_{n\text{ terms}} + 1 $$
Because $\binom{n}{k}\le n^k$, each of the $n$ indicated terms is at most $n^n$. And when $n\ge 3$, the last term $\binom n{n-1}n^1 = n^2$ is so much *smaller* than $n^n$ that the final $1$ term is insufficient to make the RHS exceed $n\cdot n^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{n\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n}{(n-1)\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^{n-1}}
&=\left(\frac{\ n^2}{n^2-1}\right)^{\!\large n}\\
&\ge1\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Inequality $(1)$ says that $n\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n$ is increasing. For $n=3$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
n\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n
&=3\left(\frac34\right)^3\\
&=\frac{81}{64}\\[6pt]
&\gt1\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Thus, for $n\ge3$, we have $n\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n\gt1$. Multiplying by $(n+1)^n$ gives
$$
n^{n+1}\gt(n+1)^n\tag3
$$
and taking the $n(n+1)$ root yields
$$
\sqrt[\large n]{n}\gt\sqrt[\large n+1]{n+1}\tag4
$$